# RStudio Connect - Intermittent C stack usage errors when downloading from Snowflake database

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Having an intermittent issue when downloading a fairly large dataset from a Snowflake database view. The dataset is about 60 million rows. Here is the code used to connect to Snowflake and download the data:

```
sf_db <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                  Driver="SnowflakeDSIIDriver",
                  AUTHENTICATOR = "SNOWFLAKE_JWT",
                  Server = db_param_snowflake$server,
                  Database = db_param_snowflake$db,
                  PORT=db_param_snowflake$port,
                  Trusted_Connection = "True",
                  uid = db_param_snowflake$uid,
                  db = db_param_snowflake$db,
                  warehouse = db_param_snowflake$warehouse,
                  PRIV_KEY_FILE = db_param_snowflake$priv_key_file,
                  PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD = db_param_snowflake$priv_key_file_pwd,
                  timeout = 20)

snowflake_query <- 'SELECT "address" FROM ABC_DB.DEV.VW_ADDR_SUBSET'

my_table <- tbl(sf_db, sql(snowflake_query)) %>%
collect() %>%
data.table()
```

About 50% of the time, this part of the script runs fine. When it fails, the RStudio Connect logs contain messages like this:

```
2021/05/05 18:17:51.522937848 Error: C stack usage  940309959492 is too close to the limit
2021/05/05 18:17:51.522975132 In addition: Warning messages:
2021/05/05 18:17:51.523077000 Lost warning messages
2021/05/05 18:17:51.523100338 
2021/05/05 18:17:51.523227401  *** caught segfault ***
2021/05/05 18:17:51.523230793 address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'
2021/05/05 18:17:51.523251671 Warning: stack imbalance in 'lazyLoadDBfetch', 113 then 114
```

To try to get this working consistently, I have tried using a process that downloads rows in batches, and that also intermittently fails, usually after downloading many millions of records. I have also tried connecting with Pool and downloading, that also only works sometimes. Also tried dbGetQuery, same inconsistent results.

I have Googled this extensively, and found threads related to C stack errors and recursion, but those problems seemed to be consistent (unlike this one that works sometimes) and I'm not sure what I can do if there is some recursive process running as part of this download.

We are running this on a Connect server with 125GB of memory, and at the time this script runs there are no other scripts running, and (at least according to the Admin screen that shows CPU and memory usage) this script doesn't use any more than 8-10GB before it (sometimes) fails. As far as when it succeeds and when it fails, I haven't noticed any pattern. I could run it now and it fail, then immediately run it again and it works. When it succeeds, it takes about 7-8 minutes. When it fails, it generally fails after anywhere from 3-8 minutes. All packages are the newest versions, and this has always worked inconsistently, so cannot think of anything to roll back.

Any ideas for troubleshooting, or alternate approach ideas, are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering why you are trying to download a large dataset like that from Snowflake - especially using R?

Comment: We use RStudio connect to process data in RMDs, and I need record-level data in this case. I'm wondering why it works sometimes and not others.

Comment: Have you looked at using the Snowflake dplyr connector for R?

Comment: @MikeWalton's suggestion is definitely worth trying. In theory all the Snowflake connectors should work however they are not, in my opinion, designed for processing large volumes of data - if you want to pull millions of rows out of Snowflake you should be using COPY INTO to move the data into a stage where you can access it. Obviously I don't know anything about your environment but it seems strange to me that you are pulling this data out of Snowflake in order to process it in RStudio - why not use RStudio to process it in Snowflake, taking advantage of Snowflake's processing power?

Comment: After posting this, I started working on a bulk unload version and have that working ok now, and it's much faster than downloading all those rows. As far as why processing it in R, the R process we have was set up before one of the main datasets was put into snowflake. Before that they were large flat files on our local server. We are working towards doing more stuff in Snowflake to take advantage of the processing power.

Comment: dplyr will essentially translate your R code into SQL and push it down to Snowflake to execute directly against a table.  Assuming there aren't any functions that aren't dplyr compatible, it'd mean no code rewrite and no data movement.  Highly suggest giving it a look.